# Use a PDF for iOS application icon

Tags: image, pdf, xamarin.ios, vector-graphics, application-icon

For asset catalog icons, Xamarin lets [specify a single PDF](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/displaying-an-image/#Using_Vector_Images_in_Asset_Catalogs), and it does all the bitmap conversion for you.

Is there a similar method available for the application icons? It would be nice to not have to generate by hand all the different sizes required?

Comment: No method, we must provide all kinds size of icon.